# In Complex sample analysis what is weight variable?

Tags: statistical-significance, biostatistics

Using PPS sampling 30 clusters were selected from large province. From each cluster 40 individuals were randomly included in sample. Few clusters have less than 40 individuals due to some limitations while few clusters have more than 40 individuals. 
Sampled Clusters becomes of unequal size. Literature suggests some weights needs to give these cluster.
How to analyze this data set.  Outcome variable is yes/no type.